# Why is github showing different authorname?

Tags: git, github, author

I cloned fresh repo of my code.
Then I made necessary changes in repo followed by these three steps

```
git add --all
git commit
git push -u origin master
```

It asks username,password, which I enter.

but after the push, git repo shows changes  authored by my colleague rather than what I am. Why so?
can't get it.

Comment: Did you change your config settings in Git? You might also want to use SSH for simplified push onto GitHub.

Comment: maybe you logged in accidentally with your colleagues username ?

Comment: Does `git config --list | grep user` show your name, or your colleagues name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what is the email in the config

```
git config --global user.email
```

if it is not yours, change and commit again:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Comment: `git config --list --global` may be also useful

Comment: Indeed it was global configuration issue! It was configured to my colleagues name and email. Being new to git, it was difficult for me to figure out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Does it locally show the author of your commit as your colleague when you do `git log`?

You can check "who you're committing as" by running these commands:

```
git config user.name

git config --global user.name
```

And [ensure your email is properly associated with your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/). You can check your local email address settings the same way:

```
git config user.email

git config --global user.email
```